# diffrence between class scope and object scope

Tags: php, class, dynamic, static, scope

is there any performance difference ? whats the main difference anyway ?
and there is more like

```
public static function
static public function
```

is it the same ?

sorry for a newbie question
thanks for looking in

Adam Ramadhan

Comment: do you mean difference between class::hello() and $class->hello() ? I see static in your tags

Comment: i just dont get it why people are using them ? tell what the usual problem is so that i have to use static tags.

Comment: Oh Ok, I get it let me edit my answer !

Comment: There's private and protected too, and those are very different from public, obviously.
This article might be helpful: http://www.phpbuilder.com/manual/language.oop5.static.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference in the two :

```
public static function
static public function
```

Both a accessible outside of the class. In both, you can't use $this inside the function because a static function does not requiere an object to be instanciated.

Consider you have a Cars class.

```
// Constructors call to a private static function add_this_car();
$car1 = new Cars('bentley');
$car2 = new Cars('Porsche GT1');

// public static function get_created_cars();
$all_cars = Cars::get_created_cars();
```

This way a class can take care of all instances of it there is (and a reference to each). And things that should be handle by the class itself and do not requiere an instance to be created.

Comment: jessy said ( irc #php ) static means it's defined at the class scope rathar than object scope, i just don't understand static things ( i never used them ) , i mean how they work, etc in object oriented programming especialy in php. i use like $this-> not this:: or with the :: static magic thing. :) , i hope you get what i mean

Comment: Does this edit answer to your question on how to use the "static" functions ?

Comment: so the olny difference is that we dont have to init them ? is there another difference like performance or anything ?

Comment: I found a Bench here on Stack Overflow, take a look it's very interesting : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472721/php-performance-of-static-methods-vs-functions

Answer (score 1):

Think of a class full of static methods like a nifty container to hold related functions together.

Say you want to create a class full of your favorite string formatting functions.

Then you can say `MyClass::MakeUppercase($string)` to make the string upper case. You can say `MyClass::MakeLowercase($string)` to make the string lower case.

Since your utility class doesn't represent any kind of object, and doesn't have any kind of internal state to keep track of, you have no reason to instantiate objects of it. No `$myvar = new MyClass()` before you can use the functions. That'd just waste memory creating objects that never have different internal states to keep track of.

Comment: so the scope is just on class::afunction ? am i getting it right ?