# What is the cost of static and instance methods?

Tags: php, benchmarking, static-methods

I'm planning to switch access of instantiated objects methods to static methods, but I'm not sure how to benchmark it **properly** and if the impact would be worse than it already is (in my opinion, you'll see.)

I've come in a situation that I do this for every route in the application I'm working on:

```php
RoutesExample.php:

#[Routes('POST', '/somepage')]
public function doSomething()
{
   $serviceA = new ServiceA();
   return $serviceA->doSomething();
}

#[Routes('POST', '/otherpage')]
public function doAnotherThing()
{
   $serviceB = new ServiceB();
   return $serviceB->doAnotherThing();
}
```

And, by looking at it, it seems wrong. But I don't have enough experience to tell.

The idea I first thought was to set all services to **Singletons**, but I immediatly went back because Singletons holds the states in the memory. I believe I'd gain performance, but the memory side would be bad.

The main idea I thought was to use static methods in the service classes. But I don't have enough information about **PHP 8.2 || PHP 8.X**. I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472721/performance-of-static-methods-vs-functions), but the maximum version of php there is 7.0. And I think a lot have changed until now.

Comment: I doubt very much the "performance" difference between instantiated objects methods and static methods will make any difference to your application in the end. I always find that the most costly thing in my apps is database access, and I spent my time optimizing that. Also note that instantiated objects carry their own properties and static methods share them. That is an important difference.

Comment: I see your point, @KIKOSoftware. Some service classes really do not carry any properties. They act like helpers and I feel some of them should be static. The problem is the inheritance that some service classes carry with them (deep layers of inheritance...)

Comment: Performance may not be any noticable impact. If you want to benchmark take the time before and after and run a few 100.000 times. Compare what is faster. BUT, I recommend avoid static because it is not mockable if you are going to unit tests.

Comment: My idea is that the choice between instantiated objects methods and static methods should be dictated by "programming needs", not by "performance". Look here for instance: https://3v4l.org/VHgat You would say that the difference in performance is shocking, whereas I say that instantiating an object takes 0.0002 ms, on a free external service, which is nothing.

Comment: Thanks, guys. Very interesting benchmark, @KIKOSoftware .

Comment: You already found the duplicate question. There's an answer there with stats for 8.0, and you can trivially run the example benchmark yourself on whatever version you want, but the differences in *any* version are tiny - measurable in *picoseconds* per call. , The conclusion from the accepted answer stands: use whichever is most appropriate code design.